# Value error after fitting my custom model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder, mnist

I am creating an encoder on the fashion MNIST dataset. The encoder consists of three layers,  Each input image is flattened into a dimensionality of 784. The three encoder layers are with output dimensionality of 128, 64, 32. But after fitting the model, it throws a value error - `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_7: expected shape=(None, 784), found shape=(32, 28, 28)`

the code:-

```
#Encoder
input1 = Input(shape = (784,))
hidden1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(input1)
hidden2 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs = input1, outputs = hidden3)
```

model summary:

```
Model: "model_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_17 (InputLayer)        [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_43 (Dense)             (None, 128)               100480    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_44 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_45 (Dense)             (None, 32)                2080      
=================================================================
Total params: 110,816
Trainable params: 110,816
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

The error after fitting the model:-

```
Epoch 1/3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3295f6ac1688> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 3)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    723     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    726             *args, **kwds))
    727 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3194     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3195     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3196         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3197             self._name,
   3198             self._python_function,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:271 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) +

    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_7: expected shape=(None, 784), found shape=(32, 28, 28)
```

What's the meaning of this error, do I need to change the input dimension. If yes then what will be my input dimension?

Shape of the train and test data-
[image]
Thnaks in advance.

Comment: what is x_train.shape ?

Comment: (60000, 28, 28)

Comment: so this is not flattened... you can pass (28,28,) as input_shape and then use a Flatten layer insider the network

Comment: How to use flatten inside @MarcoCerliani

Comment: Flatten()(input1)

Comment: now after using (28, 28)  the error is - ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 28 and 32 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_8/dense_48/Relu, mean_squared_error/Cast)' with input shapes: [32,28,32], [32,1].

Comment: your last dense must be Dense(n_class, activation='softmax') also

Comment: after using flatten error - 
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_20'), name='input_20', description="created by layer 'input_20'") at layer "flatten_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Comment: Basically ,my objective is - Use Tensorflow and keras to implement a six-layer fully-connected autoencoder based on
fashion mnist dataset. The encoder and decoder of the autoencoder both consists of three
1layers. Each input image is flattened into dimensionality of 784. The three encoder layers
are with output dimensionality of 128, 64, 32. The three decoder layers are with output
dimensionality of 64, 128, 784. After each of the six layers, nonlinear function ReLU is
applied.

Comment: please report all the code... not only the encoder

Comment: right now I have only created the encoder

Comment: build an AE and fit only the encoder has no sense... follow this track to build an AE on mnist: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1D4dUb1quReCa3ttXEgYA78Dbhbe8coph?usp=sharing

Comment: what the meaning of this model.fit(x_train, x_train[:100], epochs=3). Why not x_trian, y_train??

Comment: Cna you please comment out the whole code so it will be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your input images are 28 x 28 images, that need to converted to a vector of 784 values. While there are multiple ways to do this, the easiest would be to use the `Flatten` layer provided by Keras. In this case, your input to the model will be the 28 x 28 images:

```
input1 = Input(shape = (28, 28))
flattened_input = Flatten()(input1)
hidden1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(flattened_input)
hidden2 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs = input1, outputs = hidden3)
```

Comment: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 28 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_3/dense_13/Relu, mean_squared_error/Cast)' with input shapes: [?,32], [?,28,28].